# Creating AngularJS directive with Plupload

Tags: plupload, angularjs

I'm working on an app that will have file uploads. I want to create a reusable file upload component that be can be included on any of the pages that need file upload functionality. I was originally thinking that I could just use a JSP tag. However, we recently discovered AngularJS and now want to use it throughout the app. So, I want to create a directive that will allow me to simply put a `<myApp-upload>` tag to stick in my upload functionality.

I first made my upload functionality it's own HTML page to make sure the AngularJS was playing nicely with the [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) plugin. I put together something like this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="resources/scripts/angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/scripts/myApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <style type="text/css">@import url(resources/scripts/plupload/jquery.plupload.queue/css/jquery.plupload.queue.css);</style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/plupload/plupload.full.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/plupload/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.js"></script>

   <div id="uploadContainer" ng-controller="FileUploadCtrl">
        <div id="dropArea" style="border: 1px black dashed;">Drag files to here<br><br><br></div>
        Files to upload:<br>
        <div ng-repeat="currFile in uploader.files">{{currFile.name}} ({{currFile.size}})</div>
        <br><br>
       <!-- For debugging -->
       {{uploader.files}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The myApp.js looks like this:

```
function FileUploadCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes : 'html5,flash,html4',
        url : 'media/upload',
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        container: 'uploadContainer',
        drop_element: 'dropArea'
    });

    $scope.uploader.init();

    $scope.uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }); 
}
```

When I drag files in, I see the file names appear and the output of {{uploader.files}} change from `[]` to the files in the uploader object. So, now I want to make it into a directive. I take all the content that's in the body tag and save it to a file called upload.html. I then added the following to myApp.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myAppUpload', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'upload.html',
    };
});
```

Then, I have an HTML file like this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="resources/scripts/angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/scripts/myApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <myApp-upload>
       This will be replaced
    </myApp-upload>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load this HTML page, the `<myApp-upload>` tag does bring in the upload.html file. However, it doesn't do any of the data binding. At the bottom I see `{{uploader.files}}` instead of `[]` that I was seeing initially when it was it's own page.

I'm very new to AngularJS, so I'm sure I'm just missing something, or doing something wrong. How do I get this directive working?

Comment: Be sure to check the [fiddles list](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/JsFiddle-Examples) for a [drag and drop upload example](http://jsfiddle.net/danielzen/utp7j/) someone made.

Comment: Well, the drag and drop works just fine when all the functionality is it's own html page. I'm just wanting to know what I'm doing wrong with the directive that makes it not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I was including all the javascript and CSS on my template HTML page. I tried moving it to the main HTML file, and then it worked. In other words, I moved

```
<style type="text/css">@import url(resources/scripts/plupload/jquery.plupload.queue/css/jquery.plupload.queue.css);</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/plupload/plupload.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/plupload/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.js"></script>
```

from the upload.html file to the main, index.html file.

The javascript was dying when trying to call some Plupload stuff in the the script hadn't had a chance to be included yet.

Answer (score 1):

We just created an Angular directive for plUpload. Check here.

http://plupload-angular-directive.sahusoft.info/

Comment: I have used this directive in my project but it is failing for IE 9 it is returning json to download in browser for first time download and from next onward it is not working. Please help.

Comment: It should work on IE9, I don't have an environment to test on IE9. If this doesn't work then you should try using https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

Comment: proper documentation not provided.

Comment: That link has the documentation.